# genisoimage garbles filenames

Tags: linux, rpm, iso

I am trying to build an ISO image for an offline RPM repository. I have the files and structure I need, but when I create the ISO image, the filenames are garbled:

```
ConsoleKit-32bit-0.2.10-64.65.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Becomes

```
ConsoleKit-32bit-0.2.10-64..r
```

I have tried this with the following options on the command line and had the same results:

```
genisoimage -f -U -o update.iso /data/iso
genisoimage -f -l -allow-lowercase -o update.iso /data/iso
genisoimage -f -l -allow-leading-dots -relaxed-filenames -allow-lowercase -allow-multidot -no-iso-translate -o update.iso /data/iso
```

Is there anything I might be missing that would allow the filenames to be preserved? This is critical for the ISO repo to work properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As David Bugg's answer suggests, the flags you've enabled don't actually allow your file names to be their full length.

Pure ISO 9660 supports only 31 character file names, including a 3 character extension *(genisoimage limits this to 8.3 format normally, but you're using -l which disables that limitation and allows the full 31)*. The file with the truncated name you mentioned was truncated to 29 characters including one character in the extension, so 31 including the two blank characters in the extension.

Joliet allows up to 64 unicode character names, and can be longer (103) with the flag David Bugg suggested. This however only works on Windows and to some extent Linux. The *genisoimage man page* suggests using -R (or -r which has better defaults for ownership) in addition since the Rock Ridge standard supports 255 byte file names and folder depths greater than 8 directories, and is a real standard unlike joliet.

There's no mention whether Windows supports Rock Ridge, but I doubt it does, so I'd recommend using both so Windows users don't mount the ISO in their drive to examine it and see broken file names.

add `-J -joliet-long -r` to your command and you should have no problems.

*Final command updated from nakedhitman's comment:*

```
genisoimage -f -J -joliet-long -r -allow-lowercase -allow-multidot -o update.iso /data/iso
```

Comment: My final, working command is: genisoimage -f -r -allow-lowercase -allow-multidot -o update.iso /data/iso

Answer (score 4):

You're missing `-joliet-long`.

Add that together with `-U -r` and it should be good.

Comment: you should probably add -J in addition - i'm not sure -joliet-long would really be valid without that.

Comment: Also, use -r. direct from the man page:
For greater portability, consider using both Joliet and Rock Ridge extensions. Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Ridge) states that rock ridge allows file names up to 255 characters, and is an actual standard, unlike joliet.

Comment: @David Bugg, a combination of -U -r did the trick. Revise your post and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to get things going with "-U -R" which enables untranslated filenames and Rock Ridge attributes (I believe more than 8 folders deep):

Souce: http://realtechtalk.com/genisoimage_errors_with_long_filenames_and_deep_directory_structures-2092-articles